# Multithreading memory boundaries c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a longish/complex web scraping functionality that resides all within a class, e.g. ClassWebScrape.  If I was to instantiate two separate instances of the class and fire of their complex methods... in this manner:

```
ClassWebScrape s1 = new ClassWebScrape();
ClassWebScrape s2 = new ClassWebScrape();

Task taskA = new Task(()=>s1.DoThatFetchThing("address1"));  
taskA.Start(); 

Task taskB = new Task(()=>s2.DoThatFetchThing("address2"));  
taskB.Start(); 

Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskA);
```

Can I be sure that there should be no thread issues in the sense of one task interfering with the values on the heap of the object used by the other thread?

Comment: As an FYI: you should not use the `Task` constructor. Use `Task.Run` instead

Comment: Can you elaborate some please?

Comment: The `Task` constructor was originally thought for .NET 4.0. .NET 4.5 introduced the preferred `Task.Run` static method, that sets the correct parameters for normal usage

Comment: It is impossible to know, given the code you posted. None of the objects in the code included here are shared between threads, so no problem there. But, the implementation of `ClassWebScrap` may or may not have shared state, and you haven't shown that. There are also a variety of aspects to "thread safe", which may or may not be relevant to you here. We can assume the simplest scenario, in which case your code would be safe, but you haven't provided enough details to give a good answer (and if you had, you'd probably have been able to figure out for yourself the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the implementation of ClassWebScrap. You should be safe, if the instances of this class don't share any state with each other (for instance through static fields).

Comment: No, nothing shared.

Comment: So you should be safe.

Comment: A side note - one thing worth remembering is that there is a concurrent connection limit in .NET, which is 2 by default. If you want to do more concurrect conections you need to increase it by setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`.